# How to clear the contents of <div> using button

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have written php code to retrieve data from database to div in webpage.i have another form that has a submit button,when i click on that button that will do a function of retrieving the database values and that values will be displayed in a division. i have the following code in the division how to clear it using button.

this is php code that retrieves when the value is submitted from previous form

```
 <div id="result" style="margin-left:10px;">
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
    $strSQL =("SELECT theater_name,address FROM theaters WHERE theater_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']) . "'");
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<b>Theater Name:</b><br>";
    echo $row['theater_name'] . "<br /><br /><br />";
    echo "<b>Theater Address:</b><br>";
    echo $row['address'] . "<br />";
     }
     mysql_close();
    ?>
```

i have the following HTML code for a button

```
<form method="post">
<input type="reset" value="reset" />
</form>
```

i  am using this button.when i click this button it should clear the contents of division, how to do this..can anyone help me....

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset button couldn't clear the `DIV` content. You can do it using your form Submit Event. In plain javascript it should be something like this:

```
<script>
function clear_div() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
<form method="POST" action="process.php" onsubmit="clear_div()">
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jQuery if you have it

```
$('input[type="reset"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#result').empty();
})
```

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwpkB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $("#result").empty();
});
```